# Random Number Generator not working

Tags: c, random, numbers

I use this function to create random numbers between 100000000 and 999999999

```
int irand(int start, int stop) {
  double range = stop - start + 1;
  return start + (int)(range * rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
}
```

When I use it like this, it's properly working

```
while(1) {
    DWORD dw = irand(100000000, 999999999);
    printf("dynamic key: %d\n", dw);
    Sleep(100);
}
```

But when I use this function without the while(1), I always get the same number.
What do I need to fix?

Comment: Made me think of http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 3):

The random number generator must be seeded with some source of entropy for you to see different sequences each time, otherwise an initial seed value of `1` is used by the `rand` function. In your case, calling `srand (time(NULL));` once before the `irand` function is first called  should do the trick. You might find this question useful: [why do i always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

Comment: I know this, but when you add srand(time(NULL)) at the start of function I get strange results as well. It's generating the same numbers in the while loop. Outside the while loop I get numbers that are very similar to each other (122933959, 122933916, 123016357)

Comment: @Bubblegun: Put `srand(time(NULL))` *above* the `while` loop - i.e. make sure it is only called once. Otherwise, it will keep reseeding to the current second, which result in the same `rand()` output until the second changes.

Comment: Ok, the while loop is now working with srand. Now I want to use it outside a loop. There it still generates similar numbers (right now: 140869140, 140979003, 141061401). I can't explain this to me

Comment: Where is the call to `srand`?

Comment: in main:srand(time(NULL));
 DWORD dw = irand(100000000, 999999999);
 printf("dynamic key: %d\n", dw);

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but something you should probably read if you're struggling with random numbers. This recent article by our very own Jon Skeet is a good intro to random numbers and the trubles one might run into: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx