# Why is this code to generate random numbers always producing the same numbers?

Tags: c++, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to generate different random number in a loop in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926622/how-to-generate-different-random-number-in-a-loop-in-c)

In this code:

```
int Randtest(int len)
{
    int test[100]={};
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        srand ( time(NULL) );
        cout <<(test[i]=rand()%10);
    }
}

int main()
{
 Randtest(8);
}
```

The output will always be a sequence of repeated numbers, like `22222222` or `11111111`.  How do I make it produce eight random numbers?

Comment: This question has been asked a million times.  Exact Duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your code is here:

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    cout <<(test[i]=rand()%10);
}
```

The issue is that on each iteration of the loop, you're reseeding the randomizer with the current system time, usually measured at second precision.  Every time you provide a seed to the randomizer it resets the sequence of random values that gets handed back, and so if you keep seeding the randomizer with the same value over and over and then only call `rand` once every time you reseed it, you'll get back the same random number sequence over and over again.  Since the system time only changes once a second, this will produce the same sequence of numbers repeatedly.

To fix this, move the call to `srand` out of the loop, as seen here:

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    cout <<(test[i]=rand()%10);
}
```

This way, you only seed the randomizer once, and so your sequence should look more pseudorandom.  You may still see some duplicate values, but that will be due to chance rather than the random number generator acting deterministically.

Answer (score 2):

`srand` starts the random number generator at the current time, given by `time(NULL)`.

Your loop runs so fast that the time doesn't change each pass through the loop, and you keep resetting your Random Number generator to the same starting point.

**Answer:**  Use `srand` ***ONCE*** and only once, ***outside*** the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Quit re-seeding with the same value on every iteration of the loop.  Just do it in `main`.