# C++ generation of random numbers

Tags: c++, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to generate different random number in a loop in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926622/how-to-generate-different-random-number-in-a-loop-in-c)

This is my code:

```
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    cout<<time(NULL);
    max=100,min=0;
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
          cout<<(( (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min)%5);
    }
 }
```

Now i get the output:

1357207288         0 1 4

1357207289         0 1 4

1357207290         0 1 4

and so on. I want to get different random numbers each time. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Move the call to `srand()` out of the loop.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore And who cares? I bet 3 calls to `rand()` don't take up one second...

Comment: I have tried moving srand() out of the loop. But i get the same result. At each iteration of outer loop i want different set of random numbers

Comment: @H2CO3 ah, true, the output is "1357207288 0 1 4" nevermind... :D

Comment: Since you say you are using C++, you could take a look at the new [pseudo random functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) of C++11, especially the class [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) which can be used to generate random numbers in a range. There is an example on how to use it in the link.

Comment: I am starting to suspect some dirty tricks by the compiler - it thinks a function is without side-effects when it isn't and such...

Comment: @arjun You have tried moving `srand` out of the loop and nothing changed? I find that hard to believe. Could you check: 1) Have you _removed_ `srand` from inside the loop and _instead_ inserted it before the loop, 2) Have you actually recompiled your program after making the change?

Comment: @jogojapan In the end I find it hard to believe `srand` being in the loop to be the error, since he puts it out, too, and it is a different number each time (given that he shows the correct output, which might not be the case seeing that his code misses the spaces present in his output, hmmm).

Comment: @ChristianRau great eye. Now to the point - arjun, what is the _real_ code you're dealing with?

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes, I noticed this. Then again, that code above isn't the code that was used to generate the output, because otherwise there wouldn't be spaces between the numbers, not to mention newlines. When the output was interpreted, and then adjusted for SO, all kinds of things may have gone wrong.

Comment: I don't believe this is your real code (it cannot possibly generate that output, no whitespace!).  Please post a **complete** test-case.

Comment: For future reference, when having code and output from that code in a post, please make it the _exact_ code that produces the output. Also please read http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 8):

The reason you get the same repeatedly is because you initialize it with the same seed each time. That is, since you are performing so few operations, not a single second has passed since the first iteration of the loop to the last one. Hence, `time(nullptr)` will return the same for each iteration.

To solve this, move `srand ( time(NULL) );` outside of the loop, which will mean setting the random seed only once.

```
 srand ( time(NULL) );
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
    cout<<time(NULL);
    int max=100;
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
          cout<<(( (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min)%5);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I tried the above code. It still yields the same result as before.

Comment: Are you sure he gets the same time every iteration (because he puts it out and the numbers look different to me)?

Comment: @ChristianRau That's a valid point. In his example data, there is a +1 second increase between calls. The interesting question is: Is his code and data copy-pasted or recreated while writing the post?

Comment: IMHO the output doesn't seem to be generated from that code

Comment: @Agentlien In the end his code misses the spaces present in his output, which makes me believe he didn't even show the correct output, so you might be right with your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You must move `srand()` outside of your loop, otherwise you receive the same numbers.

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
cout<<time(NULL);
max=100,
for(j=0;j<3;j++)
{
      cout<<(( (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min)%5);
}
}
```

If you don't you will use the same seed since the time will not change in the nanoseconds your program takes to execute.

Comment: I tried the above code. Still gives same set of random numbers

Comment: @arjun What is the variable min in this case?

Comment: Its 0.. And sorry my bad... Its workin now.. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
srand(time(NULL));
printf("%d", rand() % 10+1);
for(i=1; i<rand()% max_length; i++) {
  printf("%ld", rand() % 10);
}
```

This will generate random numbers (also random length of them).

Answer (score 1):

You get the same results even with srand() out of the loop because in C the generation algorithm used by rand is guaranteed to only be advanced by calls to this function. In C++, this constraint is relaxed, and a library implementation is allowed to advance the generator on other circumstances (such as calls to elements of `<random>`). Put a sleep inside the loop and see what happens.

Obviously in plain C this doesn't happen.
However, boost libraries offers you some good PRNG functionality. Use it instead of the broken `srand(time(NULL));`

Comment: I tried using sleep. Yields the same result :(

Comment: recompile it in plain C and execute it... it should spit out different numbers. And hey, you posted an output which doesn't seem to be generated by your program!

Comment: I don't follow this explanation; of course the state of `rand` is only advanced by calls to `rand`; how does this cause the observed problem?

Comment: the state of rand is only advanced by calls to rand in C. In C++ this is not guaranteed http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/