# Same random numbers generated every time in C++

Tags: c++, random

Here is the code I have:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int sleeptime = atoi(argv[1]);    
    int sleepCount = atoi(argv[2]);

    int sleepTimeRandom = 1 + (rand() % (int)(sleeptime));
    int sleepCountRandom = 1 + (rand() % (int)(sleepCount));

    sleepTimeRandom = sleepTimeRandom * 1000;

    DWORD id = GetCurrentProcessId();

    cout << "\n\nProcess with id " << id << " will sleep for " << sleepTimeRandom << " milliseconds\n";
    cout << "\n\nProcess with id " << id << " will sleep " << sleepCountRandom << " times \n";
```

When I call the exe like

```
sleeper 4 4
```

I always get 2000 milliseconds, 4 times.. Why?

Comment: hint: read up on rand and seeding random number generators.

Comment: Looks like no calls to [srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)?

Comment: Need to call srand() to see functions.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926622/how-to-generate-different-random-number-in-a-loop-in-c

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must seed the random number generator. [see here for an example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/).

## not-seeded.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  printf ("Random not seeded: %d\n", rand()%10);
  return 0;
}
```

## not-seeded output

```
Random not seeded: 3
Random not seeded: 3
Random not seeded: 3
Random not seeded: 3
Random not seeded: 3
```

## seeded.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  printf ("Random seeded: %d\n", rand()%10);
  return 0;
}
```

## seeded output

```
Random fast seeded: 7
Random fast seeded: 7
Random fast seeded: 7
Random fast seeded: 1
Random fast seeded: 1
Random fast seeded: 1
Random fast seeded: 5
Random fast seeded: 5
Random fast seeded: 5
Random fast seeded: 5
```

## fast-seeded.c

If you want to be able to call your utility more than once a second, you will have to use a different source for you seed, otherwise you will still end up with some repeated random numbers.

Here is an example that uses nanoseconds instead of `time()` which only returns seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);

    /* using nano-seconds instead of seconds */
    srand((time_t)ts.tv_nsec);

    printf ("Random fast seeded: %d\n", rand()%10);
    return 0;
}
```

## fast-seeded output

You can see here that the numbers aren't grouped as much as the previous example.

```
Random fast seeded: 9
Random fast seeded: 6
Random fast seeded: 5
Random fast seeded: 6
Random fast seeded: 1
Random fast seeded: 1
Random fast seeded: 9
Random fast seeded: 4
Random fast seeded: 3
Random fast seeded: 2
```

## uniformly distributed random numbers

If you are interested in uniformly distributed random numbers, you should see **user3003631**'s answer below. If you are in fact using C++, that's how I would recommend doing random numbers. [More information here too on this.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/)

Answer (score 10):

There is also the random utility here in C++
in case you want a different approach  ... potentially higher quality
Please excuse the minimum of explanation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

int random_test_200()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> ud(1,9);
    mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::vector<int> v1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
    {
        auto x = ud(mt);
        v1.push_back(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer here, the C rand library should be avoided like the plague

Answer (score 2):

You need to seed the random number generator with the `time()` function in order to make sure the RNG behaves in a random-like fashion. Add the `srand()` call before you start generating random numbers.

Comment: What rkyser said, got ninja'd :P