# C++ random_shuffle is always giving the same results

Tags: c++, c++11, libc++, apple-clang

The following call for random shuffle is always giving the same results for the vector `v`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    std::srand(time(0));
    std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        printf("%d ", v[i]); printf("\n");
    }

    printf("%d\n", std::rand() % 100);
}
```

I've tried compiling using

```
g++ -std=c++0x
g++ -std=c++11
```

But both give the same results every time so I don't really understand what's going on.

```
$./a.out
7 1 4 6 8 9 5 2 3 10 
26
$ ./a.out
7 1 4 6 8 9 5 2 3 10 
41
$ ./a.out
7 1 4 6 8 9 5 2 3 10 
39
```

Comment: Where/when do you call `srand(time(0));`? How are you testing?

Comment: May be relevent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926622/how-to-generate-different-random-numbers-in-a-loop-in-c

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide a **complete** program when asking "why doesn't this code work?" so we don't have to waste our time adding the missing code that you already have sitting in front of you.

Comment: Why aren't you using [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: @AnaEchavarria it always generates different result for me. However it must always generate the same result if launched within the same second.

Comment: What's your GCC version?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not including the entire code. I have done that now. I still get the same result when running more than one second apart. 
I'm not sure if this is a problem with my compiler or how I can fix it and I would appreciate your help since I can't find my answer in the other forums.
`$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: This is clang/libc++. Their `random_shuffle` doesn't use `rand` as the source of randomness.

Comment: Don't use the two parameter version of `random_shuffle`. The source of randomness is implementation defined.

Answer (score 8):

[OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861699/c-random-shuffle-is-always-giving-the-same-results?noredirect=1#comment67012563_39861699) makes it clear that this is Clang and libc++ that they are using, not GCC/libstdc++.

A quick look at libc++'s [`random_shuffle` implementation](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm#L3109) shows that it uses an object of type `__rs_default` as its source of randomness, and inspecting [the implementation of `__rs_default`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/algorithm.cpp#L78) shows that it simply uses a default-constructed `std::mt19937` object:

```
__rs_default::result_type
__rs_default::operator()()
{
    static mt19937 __rs_g;
    return __rs_g();
}
```

In other words, in this implementation `srand` has no effect whatsoever on the source of "randomness" used by the two-parameter version of `random_shuffle`. (Scary quotes because it always uses a fixed seed.) Note that `random_shuffle` is not required to use `rand` at all, so you can't expect `srand` to "work" in portable code anyway.

Use `std::shuffle` and the `<random>` facilities instead.

Comment: If `<random>` should be forbidden for some reason (teacher or the like), you can hack your way around this by calling `std::random_shuffle` `time()` (maybe mod smth. if it takes to long, didn't test that) times. That's really a hack though, use the `<random>` stuff if possible, as TC said.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++11` mean *exactly* the same thing, so testing both is pointless.

You didn't provide a complete program (please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve next time) so I guessed at the rest of your code, and I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  srand(time(0));
  random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

  for (int i : v)
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I get different results every second:

```
tmp$ ./a.out
2 1 8 5 9 7 6 3 10 4 
tmp$ ./a.out
10 7 6 3 1 8 9 4 5 2 
tmp$ ./a.out
4 7 3 6 5 8 1 9 10 2 
tmp$ ./a.out
4 7 3 6 5 8 1 9 10 2 
tmp$ ./a.out
4 7 3 6 5 8 1 9 10 2 
tmp$ ./a.out
10 2 6 3 9 4 5 7 8 1 
tmp$ ./a.out
10 2 6 3 9 4 5 7 8 1 
tmp$ ./a.out
10 2 6 3 9 4 5 7 8 1 
tmp$ ./a.out
2 1 3 7 5 8 9 6 4 10
```

The times when it produces the same result are because the number of seconds returned by `time(0)` is the same, and so the seed for the `rand()` function is the same, and so the results are the same. If you wait a second so that `time(0)` returns a different value you should get a different random shuffle of the elements.

If the code you are running is not the same as mine you might get different results, but we can't possibly explain the results because you didn't show us your code.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I have updated the question to include the entire code. I wait more than one second to rerun it but still get the same result.
I know the `srand(time(0))` is working because if I add a like to print the value of `rand()` it produces a different result every time.
It is just the `random_shuffle` that is producing the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Modern C++

It is not guarenteed in the standard that `std::random_shuffle` will relly on `std::srand`.

--

Footnote: `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in C++14 and **removed** in C++17.

Since C++11 (the question is tagged with `c++11`), it is better to use `std::shuffle` and since C++20 to use `std::ranges::shuffle`, with an explicit randomness generator. [Example](https://onlinegdb.com/ueg57wWrz):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>


int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Mersenne Twister generator. 

//  std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), gen);
    std::ranges::shuffle(v, gen); // (Since C++20)
    
    for (const auto& i : v) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```