# rand with seed does not return random if function looped

Tags: c, random

I wrote this C code below, when I loop, it returns a random number. How can I achieve the 5 different random values if myrand() is executed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int myrand() {
    int ue_imsi;
    int seed = time(NULL);
    srand(seed);
    ue_imsi = rand();

    return ue_imsi;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        value =myrand();
        printf("value is %d\n", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seed **once** in your life, not all the time.

Comment: You're initializing the random number generator with the same number over and over again (as long as `time(NULL)` returns the same value). Don't do that if you want the numbers to look like random. Also remember to `#include <time.h>` for `time()` prototype.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Always repeated numbers given by rand()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859089/always-repeated-numbers-given-by-rand). Please use the search facilities of SO before asking a question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Seeding the generator should be done once(for each sequence of random numbers you want to generate of course!):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int seed = time(NULL);
    srand(seed);
    int value = 0;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        value =rand();
        printf("value is %d\n", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: rand() probably has a low period so I would still call srand from times to times (if in a big loop)

Answer (score 5):

Move the `srand()` call into `main()`, before the loop.

In other words, call `srand()` once and then call `rand()` repeatedly, without any further calls to `srand()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    int i = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        value = rand();
        printf("value is %d\n", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @xambo: When you call `time()` several times in quick succession, it is likely to return the same value, since the clock hasn't ticked. When you call `srand()` with the same seed, the following call to `rand()` will return the same value. As I said, don't try to reinitialize the generator every time you need a random value.

Answer (score 0):

The point of seed() is to start the sequence of random numbers with a known value,
you will then always get the same sequence of numbers given the same seed.

This is why you have seed(), it both allows you to generate the same sequence for testing, or given a random seed (typically the time) you get a different sequence each time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%ld\n", (long)time(NULL));
    }
}
```

My "guess" is that 10 equal values will be printed :)

Comment: This is not an answer. (_But it does explain part of his problem to OP_)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to reseed (for *extra* randomness) every time you call `random()`, here's one way you could do that:

```
srandom( time(0)+clock()+random() );
```

- `time()` updates once per second, but will be different every time you run your program
- `clock()` updates much more frequently, but starts at 0 every time you run your program
- `random()` makes sure that you (usually) don't reseed with the same value twice in a row if your loop is faster than the granularity of `clock()`

Of course you could do more if you really, really, want randomness -- but this is a start.

Comment: Oops -- using `clock()` doesn't add much value here since it is roughly deterministic if your program doesn't have any I/O delays.

Comment: Well unless you somehow consistently get 0, clock will add at least some extra bits of entropy, so it matters.

Comment: http://scruss.com/blog/2008/10/12/pgmrnoise-a-more-random-or-less-repeatable-pgmnoise/

Comment: `getpid()` would probably be a good addition to resolve the limitations of `time()`.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Reseeding for 'extra randomness' is like opening and closing a door several times for 'extra closedness'

Comment: @AntiEarth: A pseudo-random number generator produces a *specific* sequence if called repeatedly after seeding.  That makes it hackable.  Reseeding for every call can increase randomness.  For most purposes, it probably doesn't matter, but the fact remains.

Comment: Rolling your own security solution is a no-no.  I've presented this here as a concept for learning (based on what was being done in the question) -- not as a recommendation for serious use.

Comment: @nobar: And reseeding a psuedo-random number generator with the same sequence (psuedo-random or not) of seeds produces a *specific* sequence. Your 'extra randomness' argument takes for granted a uniform distribution of the *first* output of a generator; this sometimes isn't even true for uniformly random seeds, but here you seed with a strictly increasing large value, and some generators produce barely differing *sequences* when the seed is large!