# beginner: How to convert random generated number into number from 1 to 7

Tags: c, random, switch-statement, random-seed

I am still a beginner to the world of programing in c lang and i would like if i get your help!

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 

int main()
{
    int week;

    /* Input week number from user */
    printf("Enter week number(1-7): ");
    scanf("%d", &week);

    switch(week)
    {
        case 1: 
            printf("Monday");
            break;
        case 2: 
            printf("Tuesday");
            break;
        case 3: 
            printf("Wednesday");
            break;
        case 4: 
            printf("Thursday");
            break;
        case 5: 
            printf("Friday");
            break;
        case 6: 
            printf("Saturday");
            break;
        case 7: 
            printf("Sunday");
            break;
        default: 
            printf("Invalid input! Please enter week number between 1-7.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thats the question that i am trying to do:

"Write a C program that keeps a number from the user and generates an integer between 1 and 7 and displays the name of the weekday."

the only thing that is missing for me currently is that i want to make the usuer enters a random number then generate random number between 1 and 7

Comment: @Polat It is unclear whether the user enters a number between 1 and 7 or the number is selected randomly.

Answer (score 5):

Modulo operator `%` could be what you're looking for. On `scanf()` your user will enter a custom value that will be stored inside `week`. Then, you need to map this value to a number from 1 to 7.

Using `week % 7`, you will have a value in the range `[0,6]`, then you add 1 to fit your `[1,7]` range.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how random numbers from 1 to 7 inclusively can be generated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int value = rand() % 7 + 1;

        printf( "%d ", value );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
1 2 7 5 2 4 4 4 1 6
```

Or another example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum DayOfWeek 
    { 
        Monday = 1, Tuesday, Wednesday,  Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
    };      
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int day_of_week = rand() % 7 + 1;

        switch( day_of_week )
        {
        case Monday: 
            puts( "Monday" );
            break;
        case Tuesday: 
            puts( "Tuesday" );
            break;
        case Wednesday: 
            puts( "Wednesday" );
            break;
        case Thursday: 
            puts( "Thursday" );
            break;
        case Friday: 
            puts( "Friday" );
            break;
        case Saturday: 
            puts( "Saturday" );
            break;
        case Sunday: 
            puts( "Sunday" );
            break;
        }
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}


    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Monday
Thursday
Saturday
Sunday
Friday
Monday
Friday
Wednesday
Thursday
Wednesday
```

The program can look simpler if to introduce an array of days' names.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char * month_name[] =
    {
        "", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",  "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
    };

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        int day_of_week = rand() % 7 + 1;
        puts( month_name[day_of_week] );        
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very basically starting from this I think you can make it work:

```
int main(void)
{
    int seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    int n = rand() % 7 + 1;
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

This will generate from 1 to 7, be careful if you plan to use it as index in some sort of array because C arrays start indexing from 0.

[rand with seed does not return random if function looped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314370/rand-with-seed-does-not-return-random-if-function-looped) explains why you should call `srand` only once in your application.

Answer (score 1):

This is merely a comment, intended to illuminate the idea brought out in naccyde's answer.  You do not want a giant switch to decide what to print.  Use an array.  eg:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        const char * const days[] = {
                "Sunday",
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday"
        };
        int x = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 1;
        if( x < 1 || x > 7 ) {
                fprintf( stderr, "Invalid input: %d.  Must be Integer in [1,7]", x);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        puts(days[x-1]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```