# rand() issue in C programming?

Tags: c, random, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

So yeah, this might seem slightly noobish, but since I'm teaching myself C after becoming reasonable at Java, I've already run into some trouble. I'm trying to use the rand() function in C, but I can only call it once, and when it do, it ALWAYS generates the same random number, which is 41. I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express, and I already set it up so it would compile C code, but the only thing not working is this rand() function. I've tried including some generally used libraries, but nothing works. Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", rand()); //Always prints 41

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "For some reason"? No error messages? I find that... unlikely. When saying something(s) "doesn't work", try including what actually happens. In this case it's easy enough, but asking a complete question is just common sense and courtesy.

Comment: I don't get an error message when using it once, but I do when I put it into a loop. That's why I said "For some reason".

Comment: Yeah. So include the error message? Just an idea.

Comment: Lol, while you're here being critical (seriously no offense), everyone else has figured out the solution like 200 times. It appears to be a pretty common and solvable issue as the code is like 5 lines or so...

Comment: don't forget that real randomness does not exist; it's always pseudorandomness and generating the same pseudorandom sequence at each run **is a feature**. Likely, not useful in your case, though it is worth knowing it, I believe.

Comment: As I said, it's easy enough to solve (as is the other). But that isn't my point: "it doesn't work" is useless. When asking questions, provide the information you have. Your original question included the loop and associated commentary, so I assumed you actually cared about that part, and suggested that including information beyond "for some reason" would be appropriate. Because it would have been.

Comment: Adding the "correction" to the example code is *very* confusing, and makes a nonsense of the question.  To accept an answer is sufficient.

Comment: @Clifford, alright, I didn't know that, I'm not really a stackoverflow veteran, I already removed it.

Comment: @ShinTakezou, thanks I'll take that into consideration. Every bit of information helps.

Comment: @DaveNewton, Ah, I think I misunderstood you. Yeah, since I didn't post the for loop itself I should have provided more information. I'll delete that for-loop part immediately, it turned out to be my own fault anyway (used to Java, declared a variable in the initialization space like for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

Comment: You did originally, and included expository text--recall that SO is async and ppl may respond while you're in the process of editing. I wasn't asking you to provide more information because anyone needed it to figure out eitherproblem, I was asking you to do it because it's common sense and courtesy to ask complete questions instead of relying on others to guess, follow up, try it themselves, etc.

Comment: Be aware that the ability of `rand()` to generate a repeatable/deterministic sequence is intentional and sometimes useful.  By either not calling `srand()` at all or calling it with a constant value, the sequence will be the same every time, and this is useful for testing/debugging, when you may not want the behaviour to be different on every test.

Comment: If you call `time()` don't forget to `#include <time.h>` otherwise the compiler will assume a different prototype and invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This because the `rand()` initializes its pseudo-random sequence always from the same point when the execution begins.

You have to input a really random seed before using `rand()` to obtain different values. This can be done through function `srand` that will shift the sequence according to the seed passed .

Try with:

```
srand(clock());   /* seconds since program start */
srand(time(NULL));   /* seconds since 1 Jan 1970 */
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to seed `rand()`.

`srand ( time(NULL) );` is usually used to initialise random seed. Otherwise,

Answer (score 2):

You need a seed before you call rand(). Try calling "`srand (time (NULL))`"

Answer (score 2):

You must first initialise the random seed using srand().

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // Initialise the random seed.
    printf("%d", rand());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` gives a random value but you need to seed it first. The problem is that if you execute your code more than once (probably), with the same seed `srand(time(NULL))`, then `rand()`; will give always the same value.

Then, the second option is to execute, as Thiruvalluvar says, `srand(time(NULL))` and then `rand()`.

The one above will give you 1000 random numbers. Try to execute this code and see what happens:

```
srand (time(NULL));
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
    printf ("Random number: %d\n", rand());
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The fist idea is a bad one.  Constantly seeding the generator is both unnecessary and quite conceivably will result in a poor sequence.  The second is in fact correct and will *not* produce the same random number every time.

Comment: @Clifford Not only a poor sequence, but a predictable one. After the first 5 or 6 values come out you could technically find the seeding pattern, and predict the next 990 seeds/values.

Comment: Completely truth and sorry for the misunderstanding, I couldn't test it and just wrote from the top of my head. Now I tested it and corrected my answer but I cannot contribute much more than the former answers.

Comment: Thank you @PaulP.R.O., I'll test my code properly next time