# Custom rand() function return the same value

Tags: c++, c, random

For reference, I followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c).

I call this function from the `main()` function which return a random value in range `[0, N]` :

```
int randr(int min, int max) { int r = (rand() % (max+1-min)+min); return r; }
```

eg:

```
int main()
{
unsigned int r=128;
while(r--)
{
    int a = randr(0, 63);
    int b = randr(64, 127);
    printf("%d   %d\n", a, b);
}
return 0;
}
```

The problem is, each time the program is executed, the variable `a` and `b` contain always the same generated value, why *(I mean it printf always the same data on the terminal)* ?

Comment: Any C random numbers tutorial would give the answer.

Comment: You need to set your random seed before using rand().

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

Comment: Did'nt see this, by the way it make this question a doublon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page of `rand`:

> The `rand()` function returns a pseudo-random integer in the range 0 to `RAND_MAX`
>   inclusive (i.e., the mathematical range `[0, RAND_MAX]`).
>
> The  `srand()` function sets its argument as the seed for a new sequence of
>   pseudo-random integers to be returned by `rand()`.  These sequences are repeatable by
>   calling `srand()` with the same seed value.
>
> If no seed value is provided, the `rand()` function is automatically seeded with a
>   value of 1.

The last sentence is especially relevant. With the same seed you will always get the same sequence of pseudo-random-numbers. And since you do not use `srand()` explicitly, your seed is always 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking a look at C++'s [srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to seed the random sequence with something different every time.

The most usual is `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the seed is the same rand will generate the same sequence.