# srand(time(NULL)): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++

I tried to seed the rand() function

[Why do I always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string> 
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <future>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>  
#include <Lmcons.h>
srand(time(NULL)); 
int random_integer = std::rand();
```

But srand(time(NULL)) returned:

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

error C2365: 'srand' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'

Comment: You should be using `<random>` anyway. [Watch this.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: It sounds like you didn't include `ctime` to pick up the `time` function.

Comment: #include <random>
#include <ctime> don't make a difference

Comment: In that case you need to post some actual code. We can hardly help you without something to look at.

Comment: @user10056, Note I said *using* `<random>`, not just including it. It's vastly different from and better than `rand`.

Comment: @chris which function call should I use?

Comment: is this the whole code? `srand` should be inside a function not at global scope.

Answer (score 3):

The problem right now is that the call `srand(time(NULL));` needs to go inside a function -- at global scope, you can't just write code that will execute -- you can only declare/define functions, variables, etc.

Definitions can include initializers, which is what allows the `int random_integer = std::rand();` to work.

One obvious cure:

```
int radom_integer;

int main() { 
    srand(time(NULL));
    random_integer = rand();
    // ...
}
```

That said, you're generally better off using the C++ random number generator classes than `srand`/`rand`.

Comment: And the misleading error message is caused by the compiler trying (and failing) to figure out what `srand(time(NULL));` means in that context. It doesn't consider that it could be a (non-declaration) statement, because statements are not permitted outside function bodies. The closest guess it can make is that it's a malformed function declaration with a missing return type (which, in old-style C, would have been implicitly of type `int`).