# True random integer between 20 and 30 in C++

Tags: c++, random

Forgive me if it's obvious, but I'm having some trouble with the idea of generating a truly random integer in range, I've just started using C++.
My current code:

```
int start = rand() % 30 + 20;
```

always results in 31, as this is a "psuedo-random" integer. It is also above 30!
Can true random numbers be achieved in this way, and also, how can I actually generate a number in range?

-Jai

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand

Comment: You cannot get "a true random number" this way. To get a true random number you need a true random event. For example, elementary particle decay, white noise etc...

Answer (score 4):

A normal computer can only generate pseudo-random numbers,
but that does *not* mean that the generated numbers will be the same every time.
Your problem is that you forgot `srand`, that rand isn´t that good either way,
and that the formula should be `(rand() % 10) + 20`.

For better generators than rand, see eg. Mersenne Twister (include `<random>`).
For "true" random numbers, you need special hardware.

Comment: (Side note: Capturing the input from a microphone, if done right, is a cheap "real" random source. But even a microphone isn´t built-in in every computer, and one could argue that the environment noise is predictable to a certain degree too).

Comment: There are much easier ways of getting randomness than that. Sites on the internet derive random numbers from natural phenomena that are random (like lightning strikes world wide). http://www.random.org/

Comment: It´s easier to get numbers from random.org in a C++ program at runtime than calling a method in `<random>`? And in the case of security reasons, no internet (and no Mersenne twister) is good enough, even if the internet has perfect randomness.

Comment: Absolutely; Use the standard functions. I was just comparing your example of getting true randomness from a microphone. Which seems overly difficult (and easy to compromise) compared to other easier ways.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you might do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

class Rand_int {
public:
  Rand_int(int low, int high)
    : re(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()),
      dist{low,high} { }
  int operator()() { return dist(re); }
private:
  std::default_random_engine re;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
};


int main() {
  Rand_int rnd {20, 30};
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    std::cout << rnd() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```