# c++ guessing game error with if or something

Tags: c++

I have been trying to make a c++ guessing game and I have no idea what is wrong with my application.

The error is something related to the `if` statements. It concretely says:

`error: expected unqualified-id before 'if'`
And also it always creates the same number I've realised when  I did something that made it possible to run

The following is my application:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int svorighet = 0;
    int nummer = rand() % 10 + 1;
    int nummer1 = rand() % 100 + 1;
    int nummer10 = rand() % 1000 + 1;
    int gissatNummer = 0;
    int gissningsAntal = 1;
    string val = "";

bool spelaIgen = true;
while (spelaIgen == true)
{
    srand(time( NULL));
    cout << "välj en svårighet, 1 = 1-10, 2 = 1-100, 3 = 1-1000";
    cin >> svorighet;

    if (svorighet == 1)
    {
        bool gissning = false; //denna blir "true" när while loopen är gjord
        while (gissning == false)
        {
            if(gissningsAntal == 1)
            {
                cout << "Gissa en siffra: ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Gissa igen!: ";
            }

            cin >> gissatNummer;

            if (gissatNummer == nummer)
            {
                cout << "Grattis, du gissade rätt med " << gissningsAntal << " försök." << endl;
                gissning = true;
            }
            else
            {
                gissningsAntal++;

                if(gissatNummer < nummer)
                {
                    cout << "det är mera";
                }
                if(gissatNummer > nummer)
                {
                    cout << "det är mindre";
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "tryck på J för att spela igen, vilken som hälst annan för att stänga: ";
        cin >> val;

        if(val != "J" && val != "j")
        {
            spelaIgen = false;
        }
    }
}

 if (svorighet == 2)
    {
        bool gissning = false; //denna blir "true" när while loopen är gjord
        while (gissning == false)
        {
            if(gissningsAntal == 1)
            {
                cout << "Gissa en siffra: ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Gissa igen!: ";
            }

            cin >> gissatNummer;

            if (gissatNummer == nummer1)
            {
                cout << "Grattis, du gissade rätt med " << gissningsAntal << " försök." << endl;
                gissning = true;
            }
            else
            {
                gissningsAntal++;

                if(gissatNummer < nummer1)
                {
                    cout << "det är mera";
                }
                if(gissatNummer > nummer1)
                {
                    cout << "det är mindre";
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "tryck på J för att spela igen, vilken som hälst annan för att stänga: ";
        cin >> val;

        if(val != "J" && val != "j")
        {
            spelaIgen = false;
        }
    }
}

 if(svorighet == 3)
    {
        bool gissning = false; //denna blir "true" när while loopen är gjord
        while (gissning == false)
        {
            if(gissningsAntal == 1)
            {
                cout << "Gissa en siffra: ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Gissa igen!: ";
            }

            cin >> gissatNummer;

            if (gissatNummer == nummer10)
            {
                cout << "Grattis, du gissade rätt med " << gissningsAntal << " försök." << endl;
                gissning = true;
            }
            else
            {
                gissningsAntal++;

                if(gissatNummer < nummer10)
                {
                    cout << "det är mera";
                }
                if(gissatNummer > nummer10)
                {
                    cout << "det är mindre";
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "tryck på J för att spela igen, vilken som hälst annan för att stänga: ";
        cin >> val;

        if(val != "J" && val != "j")
        {
            spelaIgen = false;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start out with formatting your code properly to fix the error.

Comment: its something with the extra brace thingies...

Comment: The only guessing game here is for us to guess about which line the compiler is reporting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two extra `}`'s.  Once I removed them it compiled fine.

Comment: I did it I think but now it makes the same numbers always

Comment: @visu Time to fire up your debugger now, and step through the code line by line.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah I guess

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ     int nummer = rand() % 10 + 1;
    int nummer1 = rand() % 100 + 1;
    int nummer10 = rand() % 1000 + 1; this makes always the same numbers

Comment: @visu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand