# How come rand is not producing random numbers in my code?

Tags: c++, random, while-loop, random-seed

I want to randomize variables a and b to output a random number 1 through 4 in the format of a,b. However, when I run my following code, the output is always the same no matter how many times I run it. For example, the output is always: 4,3 (same output shown 10 times.)

What did I do wrong here? Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int x;
    int a, b;
    a= rand() % 4 + 1; 
    b= rand() % 4 + 1;
    x = 0;

    while (x < 10) {
    x++;

    cout << a << "," << b << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

Comment: You need to set `a` and `b` _inside_ the loop otherwise they only get set once before the loop and never change.

Comment: Because it's not seeded, as well, http://c-faq.com/lib/srand.html.

Comment: I see what I did wrong now. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Are you sure? I wonder why voting up on incorrect comment!

Comment: Some entertaining and educational viewing on generating random numbers in the modern day: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Answer (score 0):

> What did I do wrong here? Can someone point me in the right direction?
>   Thanks!

You are setting `a` and `b` once and therefore they have the same value. To fix this, set them inside the loop to give them a new value each iteration:

```
while (x < 10) {
    x++;
    a = rand() % 4 + 1;
    b = rand() % 4 + 1;

    cout << a << "," << b << endl;
}
```

If you don't want the same values each time, you can call

```
srand(time(0)); // before the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the time seed first then call `rand()` otherwise you'll get always the same values:

```
int a, b;        //store random number
std::srand(std::time(0)); // set the time seed   

for(int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
{
    a = rand() % 4 + 1;
    b = rand() % 4 + 1;
    cout << a << "\t" << b << endl;
}
```

- Don't forget to include `<ctime>` header.