# The code is required to make a random number then keepon spouting random numbers until it reaches that number, but its always the same

Tags: c, random

Here's the idea of the code: The code is required to make a random number then keepon spouting random numbers until it reaches that number, but its always the same.
heres the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int rdt () {
long long int randomonium;
randomonium=rand();
return randomonium;
}
int main (){
int rd;
int no;

while(1){
rd=rand();
printf("%d\n", rd);
if (rd== rdt()){
    break;

}
}
return 0;




}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `srand(time(NULL));` just before the `while` to change the random seed used by `rand()`.
Don't forget to include `time.h` in the code.