# visual C++ logic game help, please

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am to create a c++ logic game with with the difficulty of 3-10 characters (@#%?) that are produced within a string randomly.  The player is to guess the random characters.  Once the player has guessed, the message of how many the player guessed right is displayed.  I am using the switch command to have the player determine the difficulty level, I am not sure how to create a random string with gen_random.

Comment: Please format this in the form of a question.

Comment: Is your question: "How do I generate a random string?"

Answer (score 0):

This was answered here on stack overflow:

[How do I create a random alpha-numeric string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440133/how-do-i-create-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-c)

This guys solution generates a random string of characters (i.e. char*) of a specified length.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework.  But remember that a character is just a number you can get a random number using [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/).  So `char x = 'a' + aRandomNumber()`