# What's the C library function to generate random string?

Tags: c

Is there a library function that creates a random string in the same way that `mkstemp()` creates a unique file name? What is it?

Comment: There is no standard function for this, but it is straightforward to write one. EG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440133/how-do-i-create-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-c

Comment: There is as far as I am aware no function to do this in the standard C library.  However this has been asked numerous times before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5Dcreate+random+string

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no standard function, but your OS might implement something. Have you considered searching through the manuals? Alternatively, this task is simple enough. I'd be tempted to use something like:

```C
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rand_str(char *, size_t);

int main(void) {
    char str[] = { [41] = '\1' }; // make the last character non-zero so we can test based on it later
    rand_str(str, sizeof str - 1);
    assert(str[41] == '\0');      // test the correct insertion of string terminator
    puts(str);
}

void rand_str(char *dest, size_t length) {
    char charset[] = "0123456789"
                     "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    while (length-- > 0) {
        size_t index = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX * (sizeof charset - 1);
        *dest++ = charset[index];
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

This has the neat benefit of working correctly on EBCDIC systems, and being able to accommodate virtually any character set. I haven't added any of the following characters into the character set, because it seems clear that you want strings that could be filenames:

```
":;?@[\]^_`{|}"
```

I figured many of those characters could be invalid in filenames on various OSes.

Comment: This always produces the same output compiled and run on my Mac unless I make these tweaks:

in the includes section:
`#include <time.h>`

..
just before everything else in `main`:
`srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));`

(Seeds random with time)

Comment: Why not `index = rand() % ( sizeof charset - 1 );`?

Comment: @pmor because I researched [how to use `rand` properly](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html) and determined the pattern you suggested to be subtly erroneous.

Answer (score 4):

There's no build in API, you may use (on *x system) `/dev/urandom` like:

```
FILE *f = fopen( "/dev/urandom", "r");
if( !f) ...
fread( binary_string, string_length, f);
fclose(f);
```

Note that this will create binary data, not string data so you'll may have to filter it afterwards.

You may also use standard pseudorandom generator [`rand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// In main:
srand(time(NULL));
for( int i = 0; i < string_length; ++i){
    string[i] = '0' + rand()%72; // starting on '0', ending on '}'
}
```

And if you need really random string you need to google [`generating random sequence cryptography`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=generating%20random%20sequence%20cryptography) which is one of cryptography's difficult problems which still hasn't perfect solution :)

Comment: Which characters do you suppose might be in this random string if EBCDIC is used as the character set?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue somehow I assumed ASCII... And to be honest I didn't meant the answer as full "give me teh codes" but rather as an inspiration.