# random() not working in C

Tags: c, random

I am currently learning C though "C all-in-one Desk Reference for Dummies" and came to the point where it starts teaching how to get random numbers. However, the sample code it gives doesn't work (the compiler comes up with an error "undefined reference to 'random'"). My code is below, copied from the book.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int hat;

    hat = random();
    printf("%d is a random number.\n",hat);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the function `random()` ?

Comment: You need `rand`, not `random`.

Comment: WHich platform? what compiler? this code compiles just find on mac with gcc versions 4.7, 4.8, and 4.9.

Comment: You might need to link to the math library. Compile with `-lm`

Comment: @awashburn Looks like all of the functions (non-standard or otherwise) are supposed to be in `stdlib.h`, so that probably won't help.

Comment: Duplicate of [What difference between rand() and random() functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726102/what-difference-between-rand-and-random-functions)

Answer (score 9):

The name of the function to create pseudo-random numbers, defined by the [ISO C standard](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-Random.html),  is `rand()`.

To actually get a pseudo-random number that looks random, you need to seed the function `rand` with `srand()`, like the following:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand();
```

Here, time `time()` function (declared in the header `time.h`) gets the current calendar time as a value of type `time_t`. By doing that, it gets a different value to seed the `rand()` function everytime.

EDIT: as pointed by vanza out in comments below, there is a [random()](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/random/) function, but it is not defined in the C Standards.

Comment: Actually, [random()](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/random/) does exist, but maybe his compiler/libc do not have it.

Comment: Interestingly, and I'm not aware of any system that actually does this, `time_t` is allowed to be a floating point number that could have a range between 0 and 1, in which case `srand(time(NULL))` would always seed the PRNG with 0. I remember Clive Feather criticizing Herb Schildt for assuming this in one of his books, back in the day.

Answer (score 6):

`random` and `srandom` are non-standard C functions. They are included in glibc on many platforms (linux, BSD etc). However, since they aren't part of the C Standard, they are not required to be available on all compilers.

All standard C compilers however come with `rand` and `srand`, so just change your program to call `rand` instead of `random`. If other sample programs in your book call `srandom`, then use `srand` instead.

Change your program to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int hat;

    hat = rand();
    printf("%d is a random number.\n",hat);
    return(0);
}
```

The next program in your book probably adds a call to `srandom` to make the psuedo random numbers generated to be really random. If so, use `srand` instead.

If a beginner book on C actually uses `random` and `srandom`, then it should probably be thrown out. And any book on C which uses `random` and `srandom` without telling you that they are non-standard should be thrown out.

Comment: Actually, I'd advise to run away from any book that ends with "for dummies"

Comment: Well, it didn't say they were non-standard, but it did mention rand as a substitute for random. Thanks for the information, though!

Answer (score 2):

The [`random()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/random) function and its seeding function `srandom()` are specified by POSIX. It is intended to be a better random number generator than most implementations of the standard C `rand()` function. `random()` is included with the GNU implementation of the C library (commonly referred to as `glibc`). Using `rand()` when coding any application that relies on randomness can be dangerous if the application is expecting better random properties than what `rand()` is actually minimally required to provide by the C standard.

Windows systems do not provide this particular interface. [`CrtypGenRandom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used instead.

More information about `random()` and `CryptGenRandom()` can be found at [SEI's CERT C Secure Coding Standard page](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MSC30-C.+Do+not+use+the+rand%28%29+function+for+generating+pseudorandom+numbers) on the topic.

Answer (score -2):

i suppose u used codeblock , i use the same book, try to use cygwin instead of the default compiler