# why homemade binary search algorithm is slower than std::binary_search?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, profiling, binary-search

A simple homemade binary search algorithm is defeated by `std::binary_search` (once again):

```
// gcc version 4.8.2 X86_64

#ifndef EXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION
# define EXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION 0
#endif

static const long long LOOPS = 0x1fffffff;

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

#if EXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION
#include <algorithm>

inline bool stl_compare(const int l, const int r) {
  return l < r;
}

#else

inline bool compare(const int *beg, const int *end, int v) {
  for (const int *p; beg <= end;) {
    p = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
    if (*p < v) beg = p + 1;
    else if (*p > v) end = p - 1;
    else return true;
  }
  return false;
}
#endif

int main() {
  const int arr[] = {
    1784, 1785, 1787, 1789, 1794, 1796, 1797, 1801, 
    1802, 1805, 1808, 1809, 1912, 1916, 1918, 1919, 
    1920, 1924, 1925, 1926, 1929, 1930, 2040, 2044, 
    2047, 2055, 2057, 2058, 2060, 2061, 2064, 2168, 
    2172, 2189, 2193, 2300, 2307, 2309, 2310, 2314, 
    2315, 2316, 2424, 2429, 2432, 2433, 2438, 2441, 
    2448, 2552, 2555, 2563, 2565, 2572, 2573, 2680, 
    2684, 2688, 2694, 2697, 2699, 2700, 2704, 2705, 
    2808, 2811, 2813, 2814, 2816, 2818, 2822, 2826, 
    2827, 2828, 2936, 2957, 3064, 3070, 3072, 3073, 
    3074, 3075, 3076, 3077, 3078, 3081, 3082, 3084, 
    3085, 3086, 3088, 3192, 3196, 3198, 3200, 3205, 
    3206, 3211, 3212, 3213, 3326, 3327, 3328, 3330, 
    3331, 3333, 3337, 3338, 3339, 3344, 3448, 3449, 
    3451, 3452, 3454, 3459, 3461, 3462, 3465, 3469, 
    3472, 3578, 3585, 3588, 3593, 3594, 3704, 3712, 
    3715, 3722, 3723, 3852, 3972, 3973, 3974, 3980, 
    3982, 4088, 4090, 4091, 4092, 4094, 4096, 4098, 
    4099, 4100, 4101, 4102, 4103, 4105, 4106, 4107, 
    4108, 4109, 4110, 4216, 4220, 4222, 4223, 4224, 
    4226, 4227, 4229, 4230, 4233, 4234, 4235, 4238, 
    4240, 4350, 4354, 4361, 4369, 4476, 4480, 4486, 
    4600, 4614, 4735, 4864, 4870, 4984, 4991, 5004, 
  };
  clock_t t = clock();
  const size_t len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  for (long long i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
    int v = arr[rand() % len];
#if EXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION >= 2
    assert(std::binary_search(arr, arr + len, v, stl_compare));
#elif EXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION
    assert(std::binary_search(arr, arr + len, v));
#else 
    assert(compare(arr, arr + len, v));
#endif
  }
  printf("compare version: %d\ttime: %zu\n",
      EXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION, (clock() - t) / 10000);
}
```

### To compile the file (if saved as `t.cc`)

```
g++ t.cc -O3 -DEXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION=0 -o t0
g++ t.cc -O3 -DEXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION=1 -o t1
g++ t.cc -O3 -DEXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION=2 -o t2
```

### To test

```
./t2 ; ./t0 ; ./t1
```

On my machine it outputs (the smaller time the quicker):

```
compare version: 2      time: 3533
compare version: 0      time: 4074
compare version: 1      time: 3968
```

when setting `EXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION` to `0` we use the homemade binary search algorithm.

```
inline bool compare(const int *beg, const int *end, int v) {
  for (const int *p; beg <= end;) {
    p = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
    if (*p < v) beg = p + 1;
    else if (*p > v) end = p - 1;
    else return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

when setting `EXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION` to `1` we use:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  bool binary_search (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                      const T& val);
```

when setting `EXAMPLE_COMPARE_VERSION` to `2` we use:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare>
  bool binary_search (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                      const T& val, Compare comp);

// the Compare function:
inline bool stl_compare(const int l, const int r) {
  return l < r;
}
```

The two `std::binary_search` functions are defined in `bits/stl_algo.h` in gcc header files directory.

### The questions

1. Why `std::binary_search` using a compare function (t2) is much faster than the version without it (t1)?
2. Sometimes even t1 is quicker than homemade binary search program (t0). why t0 is so slow and how to speed it up?

---

Updates:

Replaced `random()` with `rand()`, see also [What difference between rand() and random() functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726102/what-difference-between-rand-and-random-functions)

Comment: the time gap is not big.. try expanding `arr`. (maybe.. ten times more?) Maybe you should use `<random>`.

Comment: `Effective STL by Scott Meyers`. Read from 43 onwards, they specifically deal with all the problems you have mentioned. I could have posted all his answers, but reading it from his book will make it much more clearer.

Comment: Compare the time they had and the time you spent. Also check the generated assembler for hints.

Comment: @DumbCoder Do you mean _Item 12. Have realistic expectations about the thread safety of STL containers._ ? I'm going to read it. Thanks :)

Comment: @MapX -  Nope I mentioned Item 43 onwards.

Comment: @ikh `arr`, shrunk from the real program, makes the demo leaner. `rand()`, the worse presudo random generator, outputs the same sequence each time, is good for the benchmark IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Because the benchmark is flawed.

1. You are calling `random` inside the loop (and timed) area: not only is its runtime questionable (and impacting the benchmark), but it also means that you may not be measuring the same run across benchmarks
2. Since the time spent depends on a random output, what statistical method did you use to be as fair as possible ? Average over 5 interleaved runs ? Best of 5 interleaved runs ? ...

Now, even after clearing out the rubble, you may well end up in a situation where the standard algorithm is faster than your own homemade solution. At this point, think over the philosophy of C++: *You don't pay for what you don't need*. And as a consequence, the Standard implementations are likely to be, if not optimized, at the very least *lean enough* to be as fast as the naive method: if it ever was otherwise they have been patched a long time ago!

So, finally, you are left with examining the difference. At this point you need to delve into the code and understand how it maps. I advise using the source code, LLVM IR or assembly for this exploration (feel free to ask questions if you don't understand certain transformations).

Maybe there is some unrolling going on ? Maybe the tests are better hinted ? Who knows, after a couple decades of existence you might find a pearl.

*Note: to get the LLVM IR on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com, use the following command-line `clang -O3 -S -emit-llvm -o main.ll main.cpp && cat main.ll`*

Comment: Without calling `srandom()`, `random()` outputs the same sequence each time.

Comment: @MapX: Do you mean `srand` and `rand` ? I personally know no such `random` function, and [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=random) does not either, so I thought it was a custom function.

Comment: `random()` is not part of the standard library. But `rand()` and `random()` behave the same in this question.

Comment: @MapX: I edited my answer to take into account that the `random` call might be generating the same sequence of numbers. It does not affect the time spent in this call nor the statistics method used to gather the measures obviously.

Comment: @MapX I'd try and reduce the time factor of the `rand()` call regardless, either generate the random numbers in advance (expensive don't do this unless there are only a few) or; generate random number, start timer, search, stop timer, sum time taken, loop.

Comment: @Baldrickk: Beware of the latter approach, timers are imprecise and running a timer for only very-short time spans causes high variance in the measures (making them utterly unsuitable for benchmarking). The two issues to watch for are: 1/ approaching the timer resolution, do not play with time spans less than 10x the resolution (15us or 20us are frequent resolutions) and 2/ the timer itself may introduce a substantial overhead.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Agreed. Which is why I suggested generating the numbers as my _first_ option.  I'd also personally feel happier using a realtime clock for this sort of thing instead of the `<ctime>` clock

Answer (score 1):

No definite answer to this, but I can try to give some points.

1. If you specify stl_compare, first std::binary_search calls you stl_compare and then actual operator < causing extra call. Otherwise it can simply call operator <.
2. Your algorithm has chances to betterment. For example you are dereferencing p 2 times while comparing. You can save *p into const or register or const register type to speed up things.

Can you please modify your compare function as below and give it a try

```
inline bool compare(const int *beg, const int *end, int v) {
  while (beg <= end) {
    const int *const p = beg + ((end - beg) >> 1);
    const int z = *p;
    if (z < v) beg = p + 1;
    else if (z > v) end = p - 1;
    else return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

It shows results better than stl binary search on my machine. (gcc 4.6.3)

---

**EDIT**

Completely honoring the comments from Matthieu M. I tried to recook your search recipe. On my setup, I still get results that are comparable to stl.

```
$ ./t0
compare version: 0      time: 3088
$ ./t1
compare version: 1      time: 3113
$ ./t2
compare version: 2      time: 3115
$ ./t0;./t1;./t2
compare version: 0      time: 3082
compare version: 1      time: 3116
compare version: 2      time: 3042
```

Following the modified function I used

```
inline bool compare(const int *beg, const int *end, int v) {
  if(end <= beg) return false; // Comment this line if you are sure end is always greater than beg
  int count = end - beg;
  while (count > 0) {
    const int half = count >> 1;
    const int *const p = beg + half;
    if (*p < v) {
      beg = p + 1;
      count -= half + 1;
    } else {
      count = half;
    }
  }
  return *beg == v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified and found it does not change much. t0 is still quite slower than the other t2 and a bit slower than t1 (gcc 4.8.2).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler inlines the compare function anyway, and the STL implementations are usually written by gurus.

Comment: Them being gurus does not explain the difference between their own versions.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the first answer of Mohit Jain. I have 2 versions:

**Version 1**

```
inline bool compare(const int *beg, const int *end, int v) {
  while (beg <= end) {
    const int* const p = beg + ((end - beg) >> 1);
    const int z = *p;
    if(z != v){
        beg = z > v ? beg : p + 1;
        end = z < v ? end : p - 1;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

**Version 2**

```
inline bool compare(const int *beg, const int *end, int v) {
  while (beg <= end) {
    const int* const p = beg + ((end - beg) >> 1);
    const int z = *p;
    if(z != v){
        beg = z > v ? beg : p;
        end = z < v ? end : p;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

**Running times**

> Original version: 2642
>
> Mohits version: 2435
>
> My Version 1: 2413
>
> My Version 2: 2366
>
> t1: 2606
>
> t2: 2508

The version of gcc I use is 4.7.2.

The results of t0,t1 and t2 are consistent with the OPs results.

Much to my surpirse, my version 2 is the fastest. This happens probably by accident, due to overfitting (i.e. optimizing the code for this specific test set). Also, I'm not sure why my version 1 is faster than Mohits version.

I tested various things and thought I should post the versions that are fast. To identify the reason some version is faster one should check the assembly code.

Comment: More than assembly instructions count, instruction pipelining, prefetch policy etc may play some crucial role in timing. But good work.

Comment: I agree, I should mention this too. I didn't check the assembly output, but the reason that my version is slightly faster may be that the assignments to beg/end use conditional move operations, and the first if is almost always entered (good branch prediction).

Comment: @George maybe your second version is slightly faster because the compiler can optimize pure pointer assignment more than with pointer arithmithic involved `beg = z > v ? beg : p;` vs `beg = z > v ? beg : p + 1;`

Comment: That may also be the case! I'm not sure however if this holds in general or only on this specific test set. Version 2 should take a little more time, as it excludes fewer elements at each step.