# Is there any random generator library except rand(), which developer can manually set the seed?

Tags: c++, c, linux, random, random-seed

I want to verify that if the seed is same, the resulting pseudo random number is same.
Using rand() is the simplest but I'm looking for safer way.
I found that using device entropy with /dev/random of linux is very reliable but cannot find how to set exact same seed.
I also tried cryptgenrandom of window but cannot find the way to set seed.
Can I make manual seed with those random generator, which use device things?
Or is there any other random generator library which I can set manual seed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any random generator library except rand(), which developer can manually set the seed?

Yes.
There are *many* available random number generators (and most are seedable) and all of them are better than `rand()` (which is pretty bad). Don't use `srand()`/`rand()` in production code.

Check out the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header.

I'd recommend `std::mt19937` for non-cryptographic purposes (make sure to seed it *properly*, not just with a single `int`), and `std::random_device` if you need raw entropy (be sure to check that your implementation actually implements it properly, the standard - mistakenly IMHO - allows it to fall back to a PRNG). Stay away from `std::default_random_engine`, you don't know what it will give you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `<random>` allows this, and it's a good idea to switch to it. C++'s `<random>` library is [far superior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18726221/7431860) to `<stdlib>`'s `rand()` function, and allows you to [set the seed each time.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34493057/7431860) You should be using `<random>` for any production code you write.