# C/C++ - generating a random string overwrites previous (see code below)

Tags: c++, c, string

I am trying to generate a random alphanumeric string using the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440133/how-do-i-create-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-c/440240#440240) (function code repeated below):

Code:

```
void gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
}
```

At first glance, this works great. However when I call the function twice, the returning value gets overwritten. Let me explain. When I use the code:

```
char image_id[32];
gen_random(image_id, 32); //image_id is correctly populated with a random string at this point.

char feature_id[32];
gen_random(feature_id, 32); //feature_id is correctly populated with a random string at this point. However, image_id is now an empty string?!?!?
```

`image_id` becomes an empty string. However, if I remove the last line `gen_random(feature_id, 32);` (or breakpoint before it), then `image_id` is correctly stored.

**How can this be possible?** What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the root reason to cause your problem, but it's an error: inside the function `gen_random`:

```
s[len] = 0;
```

When you are calling `gen_random(image_id, 32);`, you are assigning `image_32[32]` which causes buffer overflow as the array `image_32` has only 32 elements. Only index `0` to `31`would be valid.

Comment: I fixed this, but it didn't make any difference. Good catch tho.

Comment: +1 Yep - having a stack where feature_id is on top of image_id

Comment: Yup, writing `char image_id[32]; gen_random(image_id, 31);` did the trick.