# How to get random salt from OpenSSL as std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, random, openssl, salt

I would like to generate a random string with OpenSSL and use this as a salt in a hashing function afterwards (will be Argon2). Currently I'm generating the random data this way:

```
if(length < CryptConfig::sMinSaltLen){        
    return 1;
}
if (!sInitialized){
    RAND_poll();
    sInitialized = true;
}

unsigned char * buf = new unsigned char[length];
if (!sInitialized || !RAND_bytes(buf, length)) {      
    return 1;
}

salt = std::string (reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf));
delete buf;

return 0;
```

But a `std::cout` of salt doesn't seem to be a proper string (contains control symbols and other stuff). This is most likely only my fault.

Am I using the wrong functions of OpenSSL to generate the random data?

Or is my conversion from `buf` to string faulty?

Comment: Does `RAND_bytes()` generate random **printable** characters?

Comment: This may be useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440133/how-do-i-create-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-c/24586587#24586587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random data is random data. That's what you're asking for and that's exactly what you are getting. Your `salt` variable is a proper string that happens to contain unprintable characters. If you wish to have printable characters, one way of achieving that is using base64 encoding, but that will blow up its length. Another option is to somehow discard non-printable characters, but I don't see any mechanism to force `RAND_bytes` to do this. I guess you could simply fetch random bytes in a loop until you get `length` printable characters.

If encoding base64 is acceptable for you, here is an example of how to use the OpenSSL base64 encoder, extracted from Joe Linoff's [Cipher library](http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=664):

```
string Cipher::encode_base64(uchar* ciphertext,
                 uint   ciphertext_len) const
{
  DBG_FCT("encode_base64");
  BIO* b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
  BIO* bm  = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
  b64 = BIO_push(b64,bm);
  if (BIO_write(b64,ciphertext,ciphertext_len)<2) {
    throw runtime_error("BIO_write() failed");
  }
  if (BIO_flush(b64)<1) {
    throw runtime_error("BIO_flush() failed");
  }
  BUF_MEM *bptr=0;
  BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64,&bptr);
  uint len=bptr->length;
  char* mimetext = new char[len+1];
  memcpy(mimetext, bptr->data, bptr->length-1);
  mimetext[bptr->length-1]=0;
  BIO_free_all(b64);

  string ret = mimetext;
  delete [] mimetext;
  return ret;
}
```

To this code, I suggest adding `BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL)`, because otherwise you'll get a new line character inserted after every 64 characters. See OpenSSL's `-A` switch for details.