# Returning a random string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to make a random string using "ABCDEFG" or less(depends on difficulty(gonna be a game)), but my code keeps giving me errors like "multiple definition","first defined here".

I have too small experience on C++ (only worken in Java before, and app inventor..) so I guess I'm missing some c++ basic rule about strings/char/functions here.

Here is my code:

```
#include "Functions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


 string createRandomString(int);

int main(){

string test;
test=createRandomString(1);
cout << test;
return 0;

}


string createRandomString(int stringlength){

srand(time(NULL));

string lettersToUse="ABCDEFG";
string newOne="";


for(int i=0;i<=stringlength-1;i++){
    srand(time(NULL));
    newOne=newOne+lettersToUse[rand() % 7 + 1];
}
return newOne;
}
```

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: If you are getting errors you need to show us what the exact errors are.  Also what is `#include "Functions.h"` used for?

Comment: Well, at the very least, you don't need to constantly keep calling srand.  that will cause you to get the same value back from rand() each time until time(NULL) returns a different value.

Comment: I would recommend against using `rand()`. It is problematic in many ways. You should check out the `std::random` library instead. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you include so many unneeded header files? These should be sufficient:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

You should avoid `using namespace std;`. If you don't want to type `std::string` every time especially you can use `using std::string;`

```
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

Now to your function.

To avoid compiler warnings I would recommend to change `srand(time(NULL));` to `srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));`

Your loop is ok, yet you usually don't write `i <= stringlength - 1` but `i < stringlength`

The next `srand(time(NULL));` is unecessary.

**The real problem is your random value**: You are using `rand()%7+1`. `rand()%7` will give give you a value of range [0,6] which would be ok, but by adding `1` the range moves to [1;7] and `7` is outside of your `lettersToUse` string.

To be safe you should limit the range to what is actually accessible. `lettersToUse.size()` is 7 in your case. As we saw before `rand()%7` gives you the correct range. So going with `rand()%lettersToUse.size()` will always be ok as long as `lettersToUse.size()` is not `0`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


string createRandomString(int);

int main() {

    string test;
    test = createRandomString(1);
    cout << test;
    return 0;

}


string createRandomString(int stringlength) {

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));

    string lettersToUse = "ABCDEFG";
    string newOne = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < stringlength - 1; i++) {
        newOne += lettersToUse[rand() % lettersToUse.size()];
    }
    return newOne;
}
```

If you attempt to modify `lettersToUse` or even allow a user to specify `lettersToUse`, you should definitaly add a check for the size of `letterToUse` as the program will crash when it's empty.

If you can use C++11 I would recommend to use the C++ random number generator provided by it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


string createRandomString(int);

int main() {

    string test;
    test = createRandomString(5000);
    cout << test;
    return 0;

}


string createRandomString(int stringlength) {
    string lettersToUse = "ABCDEFG";
    string newOne = "";

    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, lettersToUse.size()-1); //Range from [0-6], when size is 7: 0-6 = 7 elements

    for (int i = 0; i < stringlength - 1; i++) {
        newOne += lettersToUse[distribution(generator)];
    }
    return newOne;
}
```

As recommended by caps here is the version using `std::generate_n`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


string createRandomString(int);

int main() {

    string test;
    test = createRandomString(1);
    cout << test;
    return 0;

}


string createRandomString(int stringlength) {
    string lettersToUse = "ABCDEFG";

    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, lettersToUse.size() - 1); //Range from [0-6], when size is 7: 0-6 = 7 elements

    string newOne;
    newOne.reserve(stringlength);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(newOne), newOne.capacity(), [&lettersToUse, &distribution, &generator]() { return lettersToUse[distribution(generator)]; });

    return newOne;
}
```

Comment: Don't use C-style casts. Rather than `(unsigned int)time(NULL)` you should be doing something like `static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL))`.

Comment: @caps Updated. Thank you.

Comment: Update is way better. +1 EDIT: Well, `rand()` use is still awful, but otherwise, new answer is decent.

Comment: @caps There is no random number generator in C++<11, is there?

Comment: `std::default_random_engine` and `std::uniform_int_distribution` are both in the `std::` library as of C++11, but not before. If I were forced to write in C++03 or earlier, I would use `boost::random` which has almost the same interface: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_random.html

Comment: I would also suggest using `std::generate_n` with a lambda instead of the raw `for` loop.

Comment: Working perfectly fine after this, I lost hope when I got the same errors after I checked c++11 in compiler options, but reseting codeblocks did the work. Thank you!

Comment: @caps Added your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

In your loop `srand(time(NULL));` give you the same random value every time. And what is `#include "Functions.h"` used for? i erase the header file also.

Here is your complete code:This function generate a random string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


 string createRandomString(int);

int main(){

string test;
test=createRandomString(6);
cout << test;
return 0;

}
string createRandomString(int stringlength){

srand(time(NULL));

string lettersToUse="ABCDEFG";
string newOne="";
for(int i=0;i<=stringlength-1;i++){
    newOne=newOne+lettersToUse[rand() % lettersToUse.length()];
}
return newOne;
}
```

> **Output:**
>         DFEEDD

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your error I can't say anything because you don't mention them. Regarding how to create a random string, this have been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440133/how-do-i-create-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-c), I paste Ates Goral code which I think is the simplest:

```
void gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
}
```

A couple of things about your code:

- You use a lot of C libraries. This is something you should avoid as much as possible IMO - you're in C++, so use C++ functionality.. there's a `random` header in C++ for instance -> have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)
- when you do include C libraries be careful what version are you including. In C++ you have two options, the XXX.h header (e.g. `math.h`) which **you should not normally use** unless there is some very specific reason, and the cXXXX version (e.g. `cmath`) which is the one **you should normally use**. The former is the C library as is, the latter is the C library optimised for use in C++, short of. It makes proper use of namespaces and has subtle implementation differences etc. In general with the latter you have guarantees that you don't necessarily have with the raw C headers.
- it's not considered a good practice to `use namespace std` the way you do, you may want to google it for more info.

Comment: You are "complaning" that OP uses C libraries, yet your answer uses C-Style arrays instead of `std::string`....

Comment: @SimonKraemer I pasted the simplest answer and a link to a whole thread which also includes more c++-style solutions. I just thought that this particular one would be easier for them to immediately use.