# How do I optimize* this?

Tags: c++, optimization

My code extract is

```
if (num == 0) {
    cout << 1;
    cout << 2;
}
else if (num == 1) {
    cout << 0;
    cout << 2;
}
else if (num == 2) {
    cout << 0;
    cout << 1;
}
```

where 0 <= num <= 2.

I am asking because the `cout << ...` statements will be converted into something much larger, but (almost) identical to each other.

*I mean optimize as 'beautify' the code (ex. remove the 5 repeated `cout` statements).

<sup><sup>I didn't put "beautify" in the question because it just sounds weird in a SO question.</sup></sup>

Comment: Use a table per value.  Feed the table per value into cout.  This is less about optimization and more about reducing redundant code and making things easier to maintain.

Comment: Why would `cout << ...` be *converted into something much larger*? They're just [function calls](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

Comment: @Praetorian I think they mean `cout` is a placeholder

Comment: Well the last `else if` can just be an `else` if you don't have to worry about anything else.

Comment: @DimChtz I meant optimize as 'beautify and/or remove repeated code (like the 5 repetitions of cout'. But any of those phrases would be weird in the question.

Comment: @sudomeacat: please put the information you gave to DimChtz in the comments (what you mean by optimize), and I'll upvote your question then, because it is clearly not a bad question.

Comment: @geza I'm sure this is the comments, but did you mean the question (just making sure)?

Comment: Yes,  I was ambiguous. I meant to please edit your question, and put the information what you gave to DimChtz.

Comment: For future reference, questions like this don't belong on StackOverflow.  If the code works in general, and you just want to clean it up and make it better, ask on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
for (int i : {0, 1, 2}) {  // or for (int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) {
  if (i != num) {
    std::cout << i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Lol - but this still has 3 compares!  How can that be faster than... waiting for an eternity for cout to run.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I understood "optimize" to mean not so much "make this code faster" but rather "organize this code better". To reduce repetition.

Comment: And I completely agree, otherwise this is a fruitless adventure with no real prize to be had.  My comment was complete sarcasm.  Forgot the markups.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this?

```
cout << "100"[num];
cout << "221"[num];
```

Comment: That is cute.  Why use 1 table lookup, when you can have 2 with 0 compares.  Nice solution.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: if you like it, then check out this :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45249531/8157187

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: woha, I didn't know that this kind of stuff actually has a name. Code golf, cool :)

Comment: That's a really creative answer, but wouldn't the result of string::operator[] be a char? (I mean I guess I could subtract '0' from it.) But it would be fun to see this in code golf.

Comment: @sudomeacat: it prints it as a char (you cannot differentiate between '1' and 1, when it's printed). If you do need an integer, then yes, your subtraction idea works. Or, you could get dirty, and use `"\x01\x00\x00"[num]` :) But maybe a proper `static const char table[2][3] = { ... };` is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's something different (without `if` or `for`):

```
cout << ( (n + 1) % 2); 
cout << ( (n + 2) % 2) + (2 - n);
```

Obviously: n = 0,1,2.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative one

```
  cout.write((0==n)?("12"):((1==n)?("02"):("01")),2);
```

Comment: 3 implicit table/strings, 2 compares, less maintainable.  I'm sorry, but putting everything on 1 line doesn't make it run faster or make it more maintainable.  The reason @Geza's answer is so nice is that it has 0 compares and the lookups he includes are very plain to see.