# generate a random string in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need help with generating a random string using C++11.

I don't know how to continue with that, if you can help me please.

```
#include <random>
char * random_string()
{

        static const char alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static const MAX_LEN = 32;  //MAX LENGTH OF THE NEW CHAR RETURNED
    int stringLength = sizeof(alphabet)/sizeof(alphabet[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i<=MAX_LEN;i++)
    {
        //now i don't know what i need to do help!
    }

    static const char test[MAX_LEN];

    return test;

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), or do you want to select some characters multiple times?

Comment: Why the use of `static` all over the place?

Comment: And perhaps `std::string` might be useful

Comment: i want to return 32 characters random in one string

Comment: Before the for loop: `string word = "";`, within the loop: `word += alphabet[rand()%62];` (62 is the number of letters in your alphabet array). Btw, char[] is pretty much C-style. Go with std::string in C++.

Comment: ok, i deleted static because its not necesary,

Comment: i don't want to use rand because its deprecated in c++11.

Comment: Look at the example for [uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and then think about how you could use those random numbers as indexes into your alphabet to pick characters for your string.

Comment: this "duplicate" wasn't in c++11

Comment: @akroma: *don't comment* your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Return a `std::string` rather than a raw `char *`.   Populate the string as needed to start, and then shuffle it.

For example;

```
#include <random>
#include <string>

std::string random_string()
{
     std::string str("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

     std::random_device rd;
     std::mt19937 generator(rd());

     std::shuffle(str.begin(), str.end(), generator);

     return str.substr(0, 32);    // assumes 32 < number of characters in str         
}
```

If you really need to extract a raw `const char *` from a `std::string` use its `c_str()` member function.

```
int main()
{
    std::string rstr = random_string();

    some_func_that_needs_const_char_pointer(rstr.c_str());
}
```

Comment: the return str.substring(0,32); gives me a error:

Comment: `shuffle` may not be the correct option here: result string will have no duplicate characters, which possibly is not the requirement.

Comment: The string can have dupplicates, btw the substring gives me a error, why?

Comment: Typo.  `substring()` should be `substr()`.  Fixed.   Yes, this approach does not duplicate characters in the returned string.   If you want to allow duplicated characters, look up `std::generate()`.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <random>
using namespace std;

string generate(int max_length){
    string possible_characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 engine(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, possible_characters.size()-1);
    string ret = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < max_length; i++){
        int random_index = dist(engine); //get index between 0 and possible_characters.size()-1
        ret += possible_characters[random_index];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [Mersene Twister 19937 generator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/) and [Uniform discrete distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/) you can generate random strings from ranges like "A-Z","a-z" or "0-9" easily.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

// Using Mersene Twister 19937 generator and Uniform discrete distribution you can generate random strings
std::string randomString(size_t length) {
    std::mt19937 generator{std::random_device{}()};
   //modify range according to your need "A-Z","a-z" or "0-9" or whatever you need.
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{'a', 'z'};

    std::string rand_str(length, '\0');
    for(auto& dis: rand_str)
        dis = distribution(generator);

    return rand_str;
}
```

Comment: How can I include my own characters without range, for example I only want to generate a random string with my custom characters `abc012-_`, do i have to do it like this? `distribution{'a', 'b', 'c', '0', '1', '2', '-', '_'}`

Comment: @Felierix no you cannot do like that you have to give range like **A-Z,a-z,0-9**

Comment: Oh so you can do like `distribution{'a', 'z', '0', '9'}` right?

Comment: @Felierix no uniform distribution only takes 2 Arguments so it can be either **A-Z** or **0-9**

Comment: @Felierix: To generate a random string with your own custom characters, you need to modify the range of the uniform_int_distribution object to include only the characters you want to use.