# How generate random string (next must be diferent of previous) in each execution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have this following code where is generated only a fixed string everytime that the program is executed, already tested in 2 computers and always is generated the same string. Then how generate a diferent string in each execution?

```
void gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum)-1)];
    }

    s[len] = 0;
}

// int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

char str[MAX_PATH]; 
gen_random(str, 10);
```

Comment: Either use a true RNG or cheat somehow like taking the hash of a timestamp (not guaranteed to be unique without unique salts)

Comment: Did you seed the random number generator in `main()`? Something like `std::srand(std::time(0));`?

Comment: Alternative methods suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440133/how-do-i-create-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-c

Comment: @Galik, thank you. `std::srand(std::time(0));` solved the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The  rand()  function  returns  a pseudo-random integer in the range 0 to RAND_MAX inclusive (i.e., the mathematical range [0, RAND_MAX]).
>
> The srand() function sets its argument as the seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random integers  to  be returned by rand().  These sequences are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value.
>
> If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1.

Same seed, same string every time. You need to srand() using a random seed. If it isn't security relevant then the time is usually a good seed. Otherwise you need to get true random bits from the operating system. Under Linux / Unix you would read `/dev/random` for that.

Answer (score 2):

`rand` generally is a Pseudo-Random Number Generator. The number sequence is fully determined by the PRNG's **seed**, as set with `srand`. Since you don't set the seed explicitly, you always get the same seed and thus the same sequence.

Please note that the newer `<random>` header has better solutions - better algorithms, better seeding, more range, additional distributions, ...

Comment: ... and is still stupidly difficult to seed correctly.

Comment: @PasserBy Because the features of `<random>` correctly reflect how stupidly difficult it *is* to correctly seed a good RNG.