# How to write a random uppercase char generator in C++?

Tags: c++, random, char, type-conversion, int

My take on this would be

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        std::cout << (char) ((random() % (int('Z') + 1)) + int('A'))  << '\n';
    }
}
```

This seems to be very straight forward. You generate a number, that is between everything lower or equal to `Z` and greater or equal to `A`. If you [play with it](https://godbolt.org/z/92ryQM), you will find that there are also other chars generated. Why is that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better `random() % ('Z' - 'A') + 'A'` ?

Comment: You probably meant `(char) ((random() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1)) + int('A'))` (which is no portable anyway).

Comment: Okay. This was obvious...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440133/how-do-i-create-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `<random>`, and not assuming ASCII, you might do:

```
const std::string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
constexpr std::size_t output_size = 20;
std::mt19937 rng{std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, alphabet.size() - 1);
std::string res;
res.reserve(output_size);

std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(res),
                output_size,
                [&](){ return alphabet[dis()]; });
```

Comment: There's nothing documented about this, but doesn't the inherit method of how these algorithms work mean your output would always be "ordered" (If A shows up in the sample it will always be first)?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Oops, indeed, `std::sample` is not the right tool here.

Comment: @NathanOliver Are you referring to the *stable* remark [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.random.sample)? It appears to be so.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not neccessarly, you just have to shuffle the outputted result.

Comment: @Bob__ I'm just referring to everything I've ever seen on a single pass sampler like `std::sample`.  I've never seen one where the output wasn't ordered the same way the input was.

Comment: @Jarod42 I like the  change, but mabye make that an addition to your answer or just a new answer instead?  All the votes and the accepts are on your old answer, not this new one.

Comment: @Bob__: `"AAAAAAAA"` won't be generated with `std::sample`, but it OP attempt's allow that.

Comment: @NathanOliver: but my answer with `std::sample` was wrong (even if up-voted)...

Answer (score 5):

```
char c = *("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" + rand() % 26);
```

is at least portable. Note the use of *pointer arithmetic* on the `const char[27]` constant which *decays* to a `const char*` type in the expression. Switch out `rand()` for something out of `std::random` if the above is not sufficiently random.

Comment: Possibly `alphabet[rand() % 26];`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Yeah, I'm trying to be cute.

Comment: Anything which includes `% 26` assumes 26 letters which is only the case in english.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: Not entirely; I'm assuming a character encoding supported by any C compiler.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis: `26` is just the length of provided string. And more languages than just English use alphabet of 26 letters ;-)

Comment: FWIW, you can make this a little shorter using `char c =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand() % 26];`

Comment: @NathanOliver that's what Jarod42 suggests in the very first comment.

Answer (score 3):

Your math is wrong. Assuming ASCII, `(random() % (int('Z') + 1)` could return anything up to `'Z'`, including lowercase characters, numbers, unprintable characters and other things. If you add `int('A')` to that, you got a high change of getting a result that's outside of the uppercase characters, and even over `127` and therefore not ASCII anymore.

You could simply have `'A' + (random() % 26)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).  You can use that to mix up your alphabet and take the first N characters you need from that shuffled string.  That would look like

```
std::string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
std::shuffle(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end(), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
std::cout << alphabet.substr(20); // N in this case
```

Comment: I like this one too, noting of course that it's impossible in this scheme to draw the same digit twice, you're late to the party. Have an upvote!

Comment: @Bathsheba Better late then never ;)  Thanks.  Yeah, wasn't sure if uniqueness was required or not.

Answer (score 0):

`'Z'` equals to 90, so the code:

```
(random() % (int('Z') + 1)
```

Generates numbers between 1 and 90. Then you add 'A' which is 65, so your numbers are in range 66 - 155.
To fix it you have to change your code to:

```
std::cout << (char) ((random() % (int('Z' - 'A') + 1)) + int('A'))  << '\n';
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would write it this way. It just samples a RNG in the range of 'A' to 'Z', and then casts it to char.

```
std::mt19937 rng{ std::random_device{}() };
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis('A', 'Z');
std::cout << static_cast<char>(dis(rng));
```