# Password generator (C++)

Tags: c++, string, loops, passwords, character

I am writing a code that generates passwords with a length of 10 characters. The requirement for the passwords is a minimum of 2 uppercase letters, 2 digits, one symbol in a random index and the rest will be lowercase letters. The code will ask the user 2 characters and it will generate characters within the given user input. What I am having trouble with is I am not sure how to make it more randomized. Currently, the code prints the uppercase and the lowercase together for example. How would I make it that these characters end up in random indexes of the password?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char minInput, maxInput;

    cout<<"Enter a letter (for minimum value)"<< endl;
    cin>>minInput;

    char min = toupper(minInput);

    

    cout<<"Enter a letter (for maximum value)"<< endl;
    cin>>maxInput;

    char max = toupper(maxInput);

    cout<<"Your password is: ";

    srand(time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

        char upper = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;

        cout<<upper;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

        char digit = rand() % ((57) - (48) + 1) + (48);

        cout<<digit;
    }



     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        char lower = rand() % ((max + 32) - (min + 32) + 1) + (min + 32);

        cout<<lower;
    }

     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        char symbol = rand() % ((47) - (33) + 1) + (33);

        cout<<symbol;
    }


return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a string instead of printing out to the `std::out`. From there, you can simply randomize your string like this:

[How do I create a random alpha-numeric string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440133/how-do-i-create-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-c)

Use `std::stringstream` to create your initial string.