# Asio How to write a custom AsyncStream?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++20, coroutine

I have actually managed to write a working AsyncStream. However, I am not really sure if I did it the way it is supposed to be done.

My main question is: Which executor is the [`get_executor()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html) function supposed to return?

While implementing it several questions arose. I tagged them with `Q<index>:`. (I will keep the index stable in case of edits.) I would appreciate answers to them.

I tried to shorten/simplify the example as much as possible. It does compile and execute correctly.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
#include <thread>
#include <coroutine>
#include <future>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/as_tuple.hpp>

#include <fmt/format.h>

inline std::osyncstream tout(const std::string & tag = "") {
  auto hash = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id());
  auto hashStr = fmt::format("T{:04X} ", hash >> (sizeof(hash) - 2) * 8); // only display 2 bytes
  auto stream = std::osyncstream(std::cout);

  stream << hashStr;
  if (not tag.empty())
    stream << tag << " ";
  return stream;
}

namespace asio = boost::asio;

template <typename Executor>
requires asio::is_executor<Executor>::value // Q1: Is this the correct way to require that Executor actually is an executor?
                                            // I can't replace typename as there is no concept for Executors.
class Service : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Service<Executor>> {
  template<typename CallerExecutor, typename ServiceExecutor>
  // requires asio::is_executor<CallerExecutor>::value && asio::is_executor<ServiceExecutor>::value
  friend class MyAsyncStream;
  /// Data sent to the service
  std::string bufferIn;
  /// Data produced by the service
  std::string bufferOut;
  /// The strand used to avoid concurrent execution if the passed executor is backed by multiple threads.
  asio::strand<Executor> strand;
  /// Used to slow the data consumption and generation
  asio::steady_timer timer;

  /// Used to generate data
  std::mt19937 gen;
  /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/69753502/4479969
  constexpr static const char charset[] =
    "0123456789"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  template<typename URBG>
  static std::string gen_string(std::size_t length, URBG &&g) {
    std::string result;
    result.resize(length);
    std::sample(std::cbegin(charset),
                std::cend(charset),
                std::begin(result),
                std::intptr_t(length),
                std::forward<URBG>(g));
    return result;
  }

  static const constexpr auto MAX_OPS = 7;

  asio::awaitable<void> main(std::shared_ptr<Service> captured_self) {
    const constexpr auto TAG = "SrvCo";
    auto exe = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    auto use_awaitable = asio::bind_executor(exe, asio::use_awaitable);

    for (size_t ops = 0; ops < MAX_OPS; ops++) {
      timer.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
      co_await timer.async_wait(use_awaitable);

      tout(TAG) << "Ops " << ops << std::endl;

      bufferOut += gen_string(8, gen);
      tout(TAG) << "Produced: " << bufferOut << std::endl;

      auto consumed = std::string_view(bufferIn).substr(0, 4);
      tout(TAG) << "Consumed: " << consumed << std::endl;
      bufferIn.erase(0, consumed.size());
    }
    tout(TAG) << "Done" << std::endl;
  }
  std::once_flag initOnce;

public:

  explicit Service(Executor && exe) : strand{asio::make_strand(exe)}, timer{exe.context()} {}

  void init() {
    std::call_once(initOnce, [this]() {
      asio::co_spawn(strand, main(this->shared_from_this()), asio::detached);
    });
  }
};

/// https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html
template<typename CallerExecutor, typename ServiceExecutor>
// requires asio::is_executor<CallerExecutor>::value && asio::is_executor<ServiceExecutor>::value // Q2: Q1 is working why isn't this working with two Types?
class MyAsyncStream {
  typedef void async_rw_handler(boost::system::error_code, size_t);
  /// Holds the callers executor.
  /// Q3: Should this field even exist?
  CallerExecutor executor;
  /// Use a weak_ptr to behave like a file descriptor.
  std::weak_ptr<Service<ServiceExecutor>> serviceRef;
public:
  explicit MyAsyncStream(std::shared_ptr<Service<ServiceExecutor>> & service, CallerExecutor & exe) : executor{exe}, serviceRef{service} {}

  /// Needed by the stream specification.
  typedef CallerExecutor executor_type;

  /**
   * Q4: Which executor should this function return? The CallerExecutor or the ServiceExecutor or something different.
   *     In this example it is never called. However it is needed by the stream specification. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html
   * I really don't want to leak the ServiceExecutor to library users.
   * @return Returns the executor supplied in the constructor.
   */
  auto get_executor() {
    tout() << "GETTING EXE" << std::endl;
    return executor;
  }

  template<typename MutableBufferSequence,
    asio::completion_token_for<async_rw_handler>
    CompletionToken = typename asio::default_completion_token<CallerExecutor>::type>
  requires asio::is_mutable_buffer_sequence<MutableBufferSequence>::value
  auto async_read_some(const MutableBufferSequence &buffer,
                       CompletionToken &&token = typename asio::default_completion_token<CallerExecutor>::type()) {
    return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, async_rw_handler>([&](auto completion_handler) { // Q5: Can I avoid this async_initiate somehow?
      BOOST_ASIO_READ_HANDLER_CHECK(CompletionToken, completion_handler) type_check;              // I tried using co_spawn directly without success.
      asio::co_spawn(
          asio::get_associated_executor(completion_handler), // Q6-1: should I use get_executor() here? Currently, I just get the callers executor.
          [&, buffer = std::move(buffer), completion_handler = std::forward<CompletionToken>(completion_handler)]
          () mutable -> asio::awaitable<void> {
        const constexpr auto TAG = "ARS";
        auto callerExe = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
        auto to_caller = asio::bind_executor(callerExe, asio::use_awaitable);

        auto service = serviceRef.lock();
        if (service == nullptr) {
          std::move(completion_handler)(asio::error::bad_descriptor, 0);
          co_return;
        }
        auto to_service = asio::bind_executor(service->strand, asio::use_awaitable);

        co_await asio::post(to_service);

        tout(TAG) << "performing read" << std::endl;

        auto buf_begin = asio::buffers_begin(buffer);
        auto buf_end = asio::buffers_end(buffer);
        boost::system::error_code err = asio::error::fault;
        size_t it = 0;
        while (!service->bufferOut.empty()) {
          if (buf_begin == buf_end) {
            // error the buffer is smaller than the request read amount
            err = asio::error::no_buffer_space;
            goto completion;
          }

          *buf_begin++ = service->bufferOut.at(0);
          service->bufferOut.erase(0, 1);
          it++;
        }
        err = asio::stream_errc::eof;
        completion:
        co_await asio::post(to_caller); // without this call the function returns on the wrong thread
        tout(TAG) << "read done returned" << std::endl;
        std::move(completion_handler)(err, it);
      }, asio::detached);
    }, token);
  }

  template<typename ConstBufferSequence,
    asio::completion_token_for <async_rw_handler>
    CompletionToken = typename asio::default_completion_token<CallerExecutor>::type>
  requires asio::is_const_buffer_sequence<ConstBufferSequence>::value
  auto async_write_some(const ConstBufferSequence &buffer,
                        CompletionToken &&token = typename asio::default_completion_token<CallerExecutor>::type()) {
    return asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, async_rw_handler>([&](auto completion_handler) {
      BOOST_ASIO_WRITE_HANDLER_CHECK(CompletionToken, completion_handler) type_check;
      asio::co_spawn(
          asio::get_associated_executor(completion_handler), // Q6-2: should I use get_executor() here? Currently, I just get the callers executor.
          [&, buffer = std::move(buffer), completion_handler = std::forward<CompletionToken>(completion_handler)]
          () mutable -> asio::awaitable<void> {
        const constexpr auto TAG = "AWS";
        auto callerExe = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
        auto to_caller = asio::bind_executor(callerExe, asio::use_awaitable);

        auto service = serviceRef.lock();
        if (service == nullptr) {
          std::move(completion_handler)(asio::error::bad_descriptor, 0);
          co_return;
        }
        auto to_service = asio::bind_executor(service->strand, asio::use_awaitable);

        co_await asio::post(to_service);

        tout(TAG) << "performing write" << std::endl;

        auto buf_begin = asio::buffers_begin(buffer);
        auto buf_end = asio::buffers_end(buffer);
        boost::system::error_code err = asio::error::fault;
        size_t it = 0;
        while (buf_begin != buf_end) {
          service->bufferIn.push_back(static_cast<char>(*buf_begin++));
          it++;
        }
        err = asio::stream_errc::eof;
        completion:
        co_await asio::post(to_caller); // without this call the function returns on the wrong thread
        tout(TAG) << "write done returned" << std::endl;
        std::move(completion_handler)(err, it);
      }, asio::detached);
    }, token);
  }
};

asio::awaitable<int> mainCo() {
  const constexpr auto TAG = "MainCo";
  auto exe = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
  auto use_awaitable = asio::bind_executor(exe, asio::use_awaitable);
  auto as_tuple  = asio::experimental::as_tuple(use_awaitable);
  auto use_future = asio::use_future;
  auto timer = asio::steady_timer(exe);

  asio::thread_pool servicePool{1};

  co_await asio::post(asio::bind_executor(servicePool, asio::use_awaitable));
  tout() << "ServiceThread run start" << std::endl;
  co_await asio::post(use_awaitable);

  auto service = std::make_shared<Service<boost::asio::thread_pool::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0> >>(servicePool.get_executor());
  service->init();
  auto stream = MyAsyncStream{service, exe};

  for (size_t it = 0; it < 4; it++) {
    {
      std::vector<char> dataBackend;
      auto dynBuffer = asio::dynamic_buffer(dataBackend, 50);
      auto [ec, n] = co_await asio::async_read(stream, dynBuffer, as_tuple); // Q7-1: Can I avoid using as_tuple here?

      tout(TAG) << "read done: " << std::endl
                << "n:   " << n  << std::endl
                << "msg: " << std::string{dataBackend.begin(), dataBackend.end()} << std::endl
                << "ec:  " << ec.message()
                << std::endl;
    }

    {
      auto const constexpr str = std::string_view{"HelloW"};
      std::vector<char> dataBackend{str.begin(), str.end()};

      auto dynBuffer = asio::dynamic_buffer(dataBackend, 50);
      auto [ec, n] = co_await asio::async_write(stream, dynBuffer, as_tuple); // Q7-2: Can I avoid using as_tuple here?

      tout(TAG) << "write done: " << std::endl
                << "n:   " << n   << std::endl
                << "msg: " << str << std::endl
                << "ec:  " << ec.message()
                << std::endl;
    }


    timer.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(2500));
    co_await timer.async_wait(use_awaitable);
  }

  servicePool.join();
  tout(TAG) << "Normal exit" << std::endl;
  co_return 0;
}

int main() {
  asio::io_context appCtx;

  auto fut = asio::co_spawn(asio::make_strand(appCtx), mainCo(), asio::use_future);

  tout() << "MainThread run start" << std::endl;
  appCtx.run();
  tout() << "MainThread run done" << std::endl;

  return fut.get();
}
```

Comment: As the linked doc indicates, get_executor `Returns the associated I/O executor.`. It's the one  your service object will use for handlers (unless of course the handler has _another associated executor_ (e.g. `bind_executor`).

Comment: Why did you use c++20 coroutines to implement the asynchronous operation instead of the standard technique?

Comment: @VinnieFalco I also wrote the same example with the "Session" object technique and just with post handlers. However, I thought this to be much cleaner and easier to follow. Also this example is very simplified in the real world these coroutines are much more complicated.
I would appreciate it if you would provide me with a better implementation (more idiomatic).
I am not sure what you are referring to by "standard technique".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Q1

  Looks fine I guess. But, see Q2.
- Q2

  Looks like it kills CTAD for `AsyncStream`. If I had to guess it's because `ServiceExecutor` is in non-deduced context. Helping it manually might help, but note how the second static assert here fails:

  ```
    using ServiceExecutor = asio::thread_pool::executor_type;
    using CallerExecutor = asio::any_io_executor;
    static_assert(asio::is_executor<ServiceExecutor>::value);
    static_assert(asio::is_executor<CallerExecutor>::value);
  ```

  That's because `co_await this_coro::executor` returns `any_io_executor`, which is a different "brand" of executor. You need to check with `execution::is_executor<T>::value` instead. In fact, you might want to throw in a compatibility check as happens in Asio implementation functions:

  ```
      (is_executor<Executor>::value || execution::is_executor<Executor>::value)
        && is_convertible<Executor, AwaitableExecutor>::value
  ```

> **PS:**
> It dawned on me that the non-deduced context is a symptom of
> overly-specific template arguments. Just make `AsyncStream<Executor, Service>` (why bother with the specific type arguments that are
> implementation details of `Service`?). That fixes the
> CTAD ([Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fhn3Grav3))
>
> ```
> template <typename CallerExecutor, typename Service>
> requires my_is_executor<CallerExecutor>::value //
> class MyAsyncStream {
> ```

- Q3: Should this field even exist?

  ```
   CallerExecutor executor;
  ```

  Yes, that's how the IO object remembers its bound executor.
- Q4: that's the spot where you return that caller executor.

  It's not called in your application, but it might be. If you call any composed operation (like `asio::async_read_until`) against your IO Object (`MyAsyncStream`) it will - by default - run any handlers on the associated executor. This may add behaviours (like handler serialization, work tracking etc) that are required for correctness.

  Like ever, the handler can be bound to another executor to override this.
- Q5 I don't think so, unless you want to mandate  `use_awaitable` (or compatible) completion tokens. The fact that you run a coro inside should be an implementation detail for the caller.
- Q6 Yes, but not instead off. I'd assume you need to use the IO object's executor as the fallback:

  ```
   asio::get_associated_executor(
       completion_handler, this->get_executor())
  ```
- Q7-1: Can I avoid using as_tuple here?

  ```
   auto [ec, n] = co_await asio::async_read(stream, dynBuffer, as_tuple);
  ```

  I suppose if you can "just" handle `system_error` exceptions:

  ```
  auto n = co_await asio::async_read(stream, dynBuffer, use_awaitable);
  ```

  Alternatively, I believe [maybe `redirect_error` is applicable?](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/redirect_error.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Coming from a java background I totally missed that I could just ignore the implementation details in Q2. I would also be very interested in your opinion on my approach. Would you rather implement it in a different way?

Comment: In your compiler explorer example you wrote `// TODO add compatibility check?`. Can you give me an example what would go there or point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's in my answer. Although in my PS I remove even the mention of ServiceExecutor there.

Comment: "I would also be very interested in your opinion on my approach. Would you rather implement it in a different way?" - I would choose either coros (and implement awaitables) OR use true generic async initiation where the caller decides what overhead is acceptable. I don't have experience writing IO objects but I imagine I'd want to see whether the "classic" Asio approach with separate implementation types makes sense and why.

Comment: Yes ServiceExecutor should definitely be dropped from AsyncStream. `my_is_executor` is a check that fails when the supplied type is no executor. I don't quite understand what you mean by the `// TODO add compatibility check?`. Isn't that comment inside the working compatibility check?

Comment: See my answer where it says [_"you might want to throw in a compatibility check as happens in Asio implementation functions"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072896/asio-how-to-write-a-custom-asyncstream/72073610?noredirect=1#:~:text=instead.%20In%20fact%2C-,you%20might%20want%20to%20throw%20in%20a%20compatibility%20check%20as%20happens%20in%20Asio%20implementation%20functions,-%3A). Again, I don't think it's required anymore (I guess I didn't understand your code enough when I was thinking of that).

Comment: Anyways, did you know you can have [stackless coroutines](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/coroutine.html) since Asio 1.10.0 / Boost 1.54 without as much overhead? It's using some macro/Duff's Device cleverness to mimic a coroutine. There's several examples on usage in that page.

Comment: I saw them but with them I would have to declare my persistent variables in the session though? After async calls the internal function state would be lost. I might consider them when I encounter bottlenecks.

Comment: `use true generic async initiation where the caller decides what overhead is acceptable`: How can the caller decide on the overhead? Also I used something similar to a seperate impl type in my real code but only to hide the shared_ptr, init call and avoid the friend.

Comment: By passing a different completion token (e.g. just a function callback)

Comment: I thought so. So with `either coros (and implement awaitables)` you mean to expose the awaitables directly for use? Did I do `true generic async initiation`?

Comment: Yes. And no. You did use generic initiation, but the implementation forces a coro regardless. (By the way just noticed that buffers are usually passed by value, and the token should probably be forwarded. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html#boost_asio.overview.model.completion_tokens.f1 for docs (but I believe you will know this already)).